# How to see this order statistic result and find my error

Tags: distributions, cumulative-distribution-function, order-statistics

Let W be a random variable with pdf

$f(w)=\theta B^{-\theta}w^{\theta-1}$ for $0 \lt w \lt B$

and 0 otherwise.

Assuming Independence,

Show that ,

$W_{n:n} \to B$ as $n \to \infty$ where $W_{n:n}$

is the largest order statistic.

I am wondering where I go wrong in my approach.

What I did was as follows,

For the original distribution , the CDF is

$\int_{0}^{w} \theta B^{-1}u^{\theta-1}du$

$=B^{-\theta}w^{\theta}$ for w in $(0,B)$

hence the CDF of the max order statistic is

$(B^{-\theta}w^{\theta})^{n}$

$=[\frac{w}{B}]^{\theta n}$

And since $w \lt B$, $\frac{w}{B} \lt 1$ and hence this will go to zero as $n \to \infty$ while the correct answer is $B$.

Comment: You have done everything correctly, but at the end you seem not to interpret your result correctly.  Perhaps by considering the case where $w \ge B$ you will see what's going on.  (Although you are not given a formula for the CDF in those cases, you know what its value is!)

Comment: @whuber  I see. Since when w=B or is greater the CDF is one hence it converges stochastically to B